# Cypress cy.get returns HTML object, but if I add .then(elem) to the cy.get function elem is an empty HTML object

Tags: javascript, cypress

Here is my test:

```
    it('tests', () => {
      cy.log(cy.get('body'))
      cy.get('body').then((body) => {
        cy.log(body)
      })
    })
```

And the output:

```
1 get body
2 log Object{5}
3 get body
4 log {}
```

So `cy.get('body')` returns an html element with 5 child elements, however when I add the `.then(body)` to the cy.get, `body` is empty.  I want to be able to save the body as a variable and continue using the .find jQuery function on the body variable. Anyone know what may be happening here?

UPDATED

What I really want to do is add a conditional.  So if an element is found then do something, otherwise do something else.  And the above seems to be a blocker to this.  So something like:

```
      cy.get('body').then((body) => {
         if (cy.wrap(body).find('.dashboard')) {
          cy.log('found')
         } else {
          cy.log('not found')
         }
      })
```

But in this case I get this error:

```
cy.find() failed because it requires a DOM element.

The subject received was:

  > {}

The previous command that ran was:

  > cy.wrap()

All 2 subject validations failed on this subject.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `find()` you can use it directly use it inside `then()` -

```
cy.get('body', {timeout: 6000}).then(($body) => {
    if ($body.find('.dashboard').length > 0) {
        cy.log('found')
    } else {
        cy.log('not found')
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding.  I took your suggestion, but am getting a new error.  I also updated the question with more details!

Comment: No errors are thrown...but `$body.find('.dashboard')` always returns 'found', whether it exists or not.  I think this is because $body = {}.  If I update the statement to be: `if ($body.find('.dashboard').length) {...}` then 'not found' is always returned.  So I think this is closer.  But it's still 'finding' an element in an empty object.  Which was the first issue I posted.  Is it possible this is an async issue?

Comment: how about you directly check it like `cy.get('.dashboard').should('be.visible')`. In case the dashboard is visible it passes if not it fails? Also if the length is less than 0 then the element is not present in the DOM.

Comment: But I do not want the test to fail if it's not visible.  I just want to test something else only if the .dashboard is visible...

Comment: Then the above code should work. we are checking the length of the element, if the element is present the length should be 1 (> 0) if not then the length will be 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234834/discussion-between-user2341537-and-alapan-das).